# Displaying guilds in Embed Pages and adding a Reaction for each guild

Tags: discord.js

So currently I am stuck at the point I have no idea how to make progress from here.
I am trying to display guilds my bot is in, in embed pages. For the each guild I would need to have numbers `ex. First guild in embed would have number 1 as reaction and so on.` After reacting on number 1 it would send a message to first guild or reacting to number 5 it will send a message to fifth guild. Maximum of guilds would be 20

Thanks.

Comment: what happen if your bot having 100 guild ? or 1000 guild there no reaction enough fo r that

Comment: Well maximum would be 20 i forgot to mention that. I would have custom emojis to 20

Comment: So If your bot is in 100 guilds and you have 20 emoji how this would work . Or you just allow it to join only 20 guilds.And you need to try some code so that we can give you a solution. We don't code your idea

Comment: well I can see you didnt understand, maximum of guilds will be 20, well yea anyways thanks ill try to code it myself